# Deploy a custom function to the cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Following my previous topic on how to optimize a complex function, I decided to write a custom algorithm because I need this task to be run locally and on machines with no access to *Mathematica*.

Unfortunately the performance differences between my *java* code and the *Mathematica*'s one are really huge and I need another solution.

I've just discovered *Wolfram Cloud* and this seems the best way to make everything work because I can just execute my *Mathematica*'s notebook, so I subscribed to the free tier to give it a try.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
optimize[d_, p_] := Module[{n, m, q, k, A, b, result},
    n=Length[d]; 
    m=Dimensions[p][[2]]; 
    vec[m_]:=Flatten[m\[Transpose]]; 
    mat[v_]:=Partition[v,n]\[Transpose]; 
    j[k_]:=ConstantArray[1,k]; 
    q=j[m]; 
    k=vec[p (d\[TensorProduct]q)]; 
    A=ArrayFlatten[{IdentityMatrix[m]\[TensorProduct]j[n]}]; 
    b=j[m]\[TensorProduct]{1,0}; 
    result = mat[LinearProgramming[k,A,b]]; 
    result 
]; 
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"d" -> "List", "p" -> "List"}, optimize[#d, #p] &, "String"]]
```

I'm using `List` as a parameter because `d` and `p` are like

```
d={7,5,11,3};
p=({{5,2,5,3,7,1,1,5,2,5,3,7,1,1},{2,8,3,2,7,2,3,2,8,3,2,7,2,3},{3,6,4,5,9,1,1,3,6,4,5,9,1,1},{4,6,2,8,14,8,4,4,6,2,8,14,8,4}});
```

Now, the function works fine in my local notebook and hitting evaluate actually makes the deploy.

The problem is that the API doesn't return what I expect.

While I expect a `string` that contains the result matrix, it outputs:

> Transpose[LinearProgramming[LinearProgramming[Transpose[{{{5,2,5,3,7,1,1,5,2,5,3,7,1,1},{2,8,3,2,7,2,3,2,8,3,2,7,2,3},{3,6,4,5,9,1,1,3,6,4,5,9,1,1},{4,6,2,8,14,8,4,4,6,2,8,14,8,4}} {{7,5,11,3}} ? ConstantArray[1, {1}[[2]]]}]], LinearProgramming[ArrayFlatten[{IdentityMatrix[{1}[[2]]] ? {1}}]], LinearProgramming[ConstantArray[1, {1}[[2]]] ? {1, 0}]]]

and I don't understand why.

Do you know what the problem is?
Their documentation is not that helpful and I'm quite clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got an answer from the support team and it seems that the type `List` can't be used but we need to use `Expression`.

Changing

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"d" -> "List", "p" -> "List"}, optimize[#d, #p] &, "String"]]
```

to

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"d" -> "Expression", "p" -> "Expression"}, optimize[#d, #p] &, "String"]]
```

made everything work.